# Magento CRITICAL Site Down: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: magento2

I changed the password in Magento admin panel and cleared the cache via the dashboard. Then my website went completely offline, only to display the multiple lines of text with the 2 exceptions mentioned.

It seems as though the database information within env.php might be encrypted because it has an additional array.

**env.php file:**

```
'crypt' => 
array ( 
  'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' (//not real key)
```

**The following is the error log received when trying to access site:**

> Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045]
>   Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
>
> Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for
>   user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I'm a non-tech guy with novice experience with web development. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Open your env.php file in app/etc directory. Check the database credentials there

Answer (score 1):

The error says MySQL credentials are invalid, please check database credentials in `app/etc/env.php`.  If the password is not correct, update the right one.
If the password is correct, try the below steps.

1. Run the below commands from the Magento root folder

   ```
   rm -rf generated/code/* generated/metadata/*
   php bin/magento ca:fl
   ```
2. If you are using php-fpm, you need to restart the php-fpm service as well. Please change the below command depends on the PHP version.

   ```
   service php7.1-fpm restart
   ```

Comment: I'm still unable to connect to the MySQL server. Does this function ['crypt' => array ( 'key' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'] encrypt the password within 'app/etc/env.php' when connecting to server? Can't seem to connect with PuTTY terminal.

Comment: did you check the mysql credential?

Comment: I updated the Magento 2 admin panel password which caused this, do I update the password credentials in app/etc/env.php to match the new admin panel password?

Comment: No! this error is not related to admin user password change. Check your MySQL credential, maybe someone changed without your knowledge.

Comment: How can I locate my MySQL credentials? I have Filezilla open but don't know the correct path to find it.

Comment: Contact your hosting provider, so you can get MySQL credentials... you'd setup them in app/etc/env.php file